# Can I call an existing function of a class with my own parameters with bytebuddy?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

In a game I'm playing I've narrowed down that there is a function attackEnemy(int var) that occurs after I select an enemy with my mouse.

I have worked with several bytebuddy agents to see the function name and parameter value when this event occurs.

But I'm having issues modifying a class with an agent in such a way that I can interact with its objects. At most I can call my own static functions that I have created.

For example, here I add a method:

```
public static void myMethod() throws Exception {

   System.out.println("My generated method");
}
```

And I can append it the class with an agent

```
public class Agent {

public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

    System.out.println("Agent for add a method ");

    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())

            .type((ElementMatchers.nameContains("myC")))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
                    .defineMethod("myMethod", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(AddMethod.class))
                    .method(ElementMatchers.nameContains("method1"))
                    .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE
                            .andThen(MethodCall.invoke(ElementMatchers.nameContains("myMethod"))))

            ).installOn(instrumentation);



}


}
```

But this is as far as I've gotten with the agents functionality.

If I change the MethodDelegation.to(new AddMethod())

I can invoke a non-static method, but I still only have access to the new class I have created and it's methods.

So I'm really failing on a conceptual level.

The end result I'm looking for is my created class to be able to call the attackEnemy(int var) function or to recreate that function entirely, but my current agent seems to only be able to create methods in its own class so I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for MethodDelegation that allows you to define a new class that dispatches a method via annotated parameters. You can find details in the classes javadoc.